# JavaScript .join is not working

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code:

```
board = [];

var rowsNum = 5;
var colsNum = 5;

function printBoard(board) {
    for (row in board) {
        document.write(" ").join(row);
    }
}

function clearAndRestartBoard() {
    board = [];
    for (i = 0; i < rowsNum; i++) {
        board.push("[ ]" * colsNum);
        }
}

printBoard(board);
```

It does not throw an error, but it does not show up in my webpage. Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Just in case, here is the html without the css:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="test.css" type="text/css"rel="stylesheet" />
        <title> Test! </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id = "script"> <script src = "test.js"> </script> </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am very new to JS so thank you so much for any help!

Comment: Your `board` variable is an empty array. Then `"[ ]" * colsNum` does not do what you think.

Comment: What do you exactly want to do?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/h294wre3/1/

Comment: @zerkms How does the empty array affect `"[ ]" * colsNum?`

Comment: or https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/h294wre3/2/

Comment: @Demandooda it does not. Those are 2 independent statements.

Comment: @iplus26 I want to make a simple game board, like this: [][][][][] with multiple rows

Comment: @zerkms Than what does your first comment mean?

Comment: It means literally what I typed: 1. your `board` is always an empty array and never modified 2. `"string" * 5` does not do what you think it does

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several issues there, but the main one is that you never call `clearAndRestartBoard`, and so `board` is empty, and so you never output anything.

Here's a list of all of the issues that I see off-the-cuff:

1. You never call `clearAndRestartBoard`.
2. Your code is falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html): Declare your variables.
3. You're using `for-in` to loop through an array. That's usually not a good idea, though there can be use cases for it; [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476) outlines your various options for looping through an array.
4. `"[ ]" * colsNum` is `NaN` because `*` will convert both of its operands to numbers and then do mathematical multiplication. The string `"[ ]"` converts to `NaN` because it cannot be interpreted as a number, and then anything multiplied by `NaN` is `NaN`. It *isn't* `colsNum` blank arrays. To do that, you'd have to have a second loop creating the row arrays, pushing `"[ ]"` into them, and pushing those row arrays onto `board`.
5. You're using `document.write`. While that will work for simple experiments, it's not something you want to use in general.
6. You're calling `join` on the result of `document.write`, which I'm fairly certain *isn't* an array.
7. I would also suggest that you *either* use a global board, or always pass it as an argument, but not mix-and-match where one function uses the global and the other uses an argument.
8. You never output a line break between rows.

Here's a minimal update addressing those:

```js
var board;

var rowsNum = 5;
var colsNum = 5;

function printBoard(board) {
  board.forEach(function(row) {
    document.write(row.join(""));
    document.write("<br>");
  });
}

function clearAndRestartBoard() {
  var row;
  board = [];
  for (var r = 0; r < rowsNum; r++) {
    row = [];
    for (var c = 0; c < colsNum; c++) {
      row.push("[ ]"); // If you really wanted the string [ ]
    }
    board.push(row);
  }
}

clearAndRestartBoard();
printBoard(board);
```

Comment: OMG! I completely made a ton of mistakes! Thx everyone for all the help, and, soon, I will be better. JS sure is different thn python!

Comment: @Demandooda: Making mistakes is an inevitable part of learning something. :-)